# How do I increase the text size of the text on a console?

Tags: 10.04, server

I have ubuntu-server on my server and also in terminals and an application squeegee in text mode. This version 9.10 of ubuntu-serversystem came with a resolution at the terminal, which makes use of the application, the fonts (letters) are very small.

Please, if anyone knows how to take the resolution of text mode 10.04 ubuntu server, tell me. To illustrate. I need the resolution is to get as Debian, large fonts!

Still using version 9.04, it was the last that still has not implemented the resolution at the terminal (text mode). I remind you that non-use graphical interface. Only text mode.

Answer (score 17):

You can also dynamically change the font size after the system has booted.

The simplest way I've found is to pick a font that you like from `/usr/share/consolefonts/` and pass it to the `setfont` command.  Not all the fonts work for me (some say 'KDFONTOP: invalid argument', possibly due to my framebuffer settings), but enough do.  If you want a large font, I'd suggest trying either of these commands to start with:

```
setfont Uni2-Terminus16
setfont Uni2-Fixed18
```

If you want to make your choice persist through reboots, you'll need to add a command somewhere in your startup scripts.  (`.bashrc` will work, but you should probably try to think of somewhere better.)

The other way is to use the `console-setup` package.  Type

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

to start it asking its questions.  Accept the defaults to start with, and then after about seven or eight questions you'll be asked what font you want on the console.  The font you select here will be stored in the initramfs, so that it will be reloaded automatically next time you boot.

Comment: On Ubuntu LTS 12.04, dpkg-reconfigure thing changes the font fine, but doesn't persist after rebooting.

Comment: Are you sure? I just do this step and it works. After a while, the font change back to the one I setup in console-setup.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand you correctly, you are arguing about the font size in the virtual terminals (VT), accessible with `CTRL + ALT + F[1-6]`!?

These terminals are configured during the boot process. Depending on your version of Grub you can configure the setup to your preferred solution:

Using **GRUB1** (0.9) open the file `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and search for lines that start with `kernel /boot/...` and add or change `vga=xxx`. A table with possible values and it's meanings can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers). So your kernel line should look like this:

```
kernel /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 ro vga=791
```

Please take care not to change anything else, otherwise your machine may not boot probably anymore!

If you have installed **GRUB2** (1.9) the `vga` parameter became deprecated. Open `/etc/default/grub` and set the following values:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

You can choose between one of these resolutions: `640×480`, `800×600`, `1024×768`, `1280×1024`, `1600×1200`.

To generate a new config file run the following as root/sudo:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

In some curious cases this might not work for you, you can instead also use the deprecated `vga` version. Add the `vga=` setting next to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line in your `/etc/default/grub`, so that this line eg looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash vga=791"
```

In both cases, **GRUB1** or **GRUB2** you need to reboot to see the effect of your changes.

Comment: The `grub-mkconfig` part is not equivalent to `update-grub`? And it surely requires `sudo`.

Comment: Also a reference to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers for resolution different from 1024x768 16bit colors is worth to mention.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /usr/share/consolefonts
ls
```

Choose one file `filex` and run `setfont filex`. For example:

```
setfont Uni3-Terminus32x16.psf.gz
```

And that should solve the problem.

Comment: *Why* would this increase the text *size*?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`

Enter, Enter, then pick VGA then a larger size. Then

`setupcon`