# Ubuntu 20.04 black and purple screen without login fields

Tags: nvidia, login, 20.04

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 on an HP Z820 workstation with 2 NVIDIA cards, 1 1030 and a 1060.

I have 2 screens Attached, one to each GPU.

When Login in the screen on the 1030 show the purple background without login fields the screen attached to the 1060 show a black screen no login screens.

Mouse works fine and can navigate from one screen to the next, so both screens are active.

I can blindly press enter and then enter my password, press enter after which Login proceed and I get a normal session on both screens.

What it look like is that the black screen is not displaying the fields but that they are active.

Any idea how I can ensure both screens show the login screen and that one of them show the login fields ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the screen resolution in your grub configuration.
When you are logged in open up a terminal and type
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
or you can use vi.
Remove the hash to enable the line **GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480**
Or you could try resolution 1280x760 which might suit your graphics card.
Commit the change and save over the same filename.
Then type `sudo update-grub` and the reboot.
Similar problem with virtualbox terminals [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577646/i-cant-change-screen-resolution-on-virtualbox-with-ubuntu-server-installed-on-i?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C46.6915) and also [read this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution)