# Ubuntu 18.04 "Failed to start Snap daemon"

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have a server with Ubuntu 18.04.5 Desktop installed. It was running just fine until I restarted it. After restart it would hang on the Ubuntu logo, screen with 5 dots, and not progress any further.

I have tried:

https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/

[Ubuntu 20.04 black and purple screen without login fields](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263707/ubuntu-20-04-black-and-purple-screen-without-login-fields)

[Problems with login in Ubuntu 18.04 - Failed to start Load Kernel Modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073410/problems-with-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules)

With no luck. Is there anything else I can do to fix this issue?
Pressing "del" gets me to the boot log(?) where it seems to constantly try to start Snap daemon

Comment: Live USB and backup. Not sure why you are running a desktop for a server. Consider a clean 20.04.1 server install. Alternatively if you an get to a shell purge snapd....

Answer (score -2):

op did you ever get this to work?  I have a live usb, what am I supposed to do after I am in a live session?

Answer:  Log into live session, sudo su for root, mv snap to snap2, or whatever.  reboot.  fixed.