# How to make terminal's font smaller?

Tags: command-line, themes, fonts, customization, default

I suddenly noticed, **fonts of my ubuntu terminal got bigger. I don't know how. How to set it to default ?**

thank you in advance,
Ubuntu 20.04

[image: terminal picture]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase the text size of the text on a console?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29328/how-do-i-increase-the-text-size-of-the-text-on-a-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the terminal and go to preferences then select custom font and choose a plain one like Monospace 12.